# How to Remove Ecto Model from Phoenix Application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I generated a model through a command like the following:

```
mix phoenix.gen.html Project projects title:string
```

I'd like to undo this action (delete all files/database records that were created):

```
* creating web/controllers/project_controller.ex
* creating web/templates/project/edit.html.eex
* creating web/templates/project/form.html.eex
* creating web/templates/project/index.html.eex
* creating web/templates/project/new.html.eex
* creating web/templates/project/show.html.eex
* creating web/views/project_view.ex
* creating test/controllers/project_controller_test.exs
* creating web/models/project.ex
* creating test/models/project_test.exs
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20170214192223_create_project.exs
```

Is there a command that can be used to do this as opposed to deleting all files manually? If so what would that command be?

For example: in Rails you could do `rails d scaffold ...` to undo a `rails g scaffold` command.

Another option would be to use my version control system (git) to accomplish this; however, a command to delete the `mix phoenix.gen.html` generated files would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Chris McCord is against implementing this feature in the Phoenix framework:

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1597

I'll have to use version control system to accomplish this.